# Could not find part of the path C:\dev\MyProject\...\MyProjectContext_IncrementalSchemaOnly.dacpac

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msdeploy, webdeploy

Using Visual Studio 2013, I created a web deploy package. I'm now trying to import that in IIS on a test machine, but it refuses to import the application because of the following error:

> Could not find part of the path
>   C:\dev\MyProject...\MyProjectContext_IncrementalSchemaOnly.dacpac

The thing is, it is specifically asking for my dev environment folder, but of course, that doesn't exist on the test server. How do I include the dacpac file in the package and have it use that one?